# How to display zero value as blank cell in mac numbers 3.1

Tags: mac, macos, numbers

How do I display zero value as blank cell in mac numbers 3.1 yet maintain a formula.  I want a running balance column that only shows balance to the line of the last entry like a checkbook register.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is to use "Conditional Highlighting..." found under the "Format" menu.

Select the cell you want to have blank as zero then select "Conditional Highlighting" you then set a highlight when the cell is equal to zero. Choose  "Custom Highlighting" at the bottom of the style list and then you can set the text colour to white. A "blank" cell on zero.

Comment: I would add that if you have interleaved backgrounds and therefore don't want white text on non-white backgrounds, instead set the text colour to have an opacity of 0%.

Comment: Good tip Timothy!!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple approach:  =If(A1<=0," ",A1)

You're simple saying:  If the result displayed in Cell A1 is less than or equal to 0, display what's between the parenthesis.  It could be Yes, No, Blue, Green, or just Blank space.  If Cell A1 is greater than 0, display the value of that cell.

You don't have to leave a space between the "" for the formula to work.  Try a simple test of the formula on different values and watch as the cell will switch to a Blank value, if the Cell is less than or equal to 0.  Logic formulas using If, And, Or and If And switches are powerful tools in many calculations goals.

Comment: the suggestion of using If(A1<=0," ",A1) does NOT work if the cell is used in a mathematical formula. As soon as the condition is met then the formula will error as it is expecting a numeric value.